Trouble sending audio via custom AudioDeviceModule with WebRTC in C++
I am trying to implement a WebRTC Plugin for Unreal Engine using C++ and I have been having trouble sending Audio via the Custom AudioDeviceModule I created.
The problem is quite simple, I can see Connection Established between Peers, I can see Unreal Engine capturing and passing audio to the ADM via AudioTransport->RecordedDataIsAvailable() but I don't see the audio passed into the AudioTransport being transported as neither the other Peer nor Wireshark can see any data transmission.
Here is my ADM code:

FCustomAudioDeviceModule::FCustomAudioDeviceModule()
{
    AudioCapturer = MakeUnique<FWebRTCAudioCaptureComponent>();
}

FCustomAudioDeviceModule::~FCustomAudioDeviceModule()
{

}

// Retrieve the currently utilized audio layer
int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::ActiveAudioLayer(webrtc::AudioDeviceModule::AudioLayer* audioLayer) const 
{
    *audioLayer = webrtc::AudioDeviceModule::AudioLayer::kDummyAudio;
    return 0;
}

// Full-duplex transportation of PCM audio
int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::RegisterAudioCallback(webrtc::AudioTransport* audioCallback) 
{
    AudioCapturer->RegisterAudioTransport(audioCallback);
    return 0;
}

// Main initialization and termination
int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::Init() 
{
    AudioCapturer->Init();
    bIsInitialized = true;
    return 0;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::Terminate() 
{
    bIsInitialized = false;
    return 0;
}

bool FCustomAudioDeviceModule::Initialized() const 
{
    return bIsInitialized;
}

// Device enumeration
int16_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::PlayoutDevices() 
{
    return -1;
}

int16_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::RecordingDevices() 
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::PlayoutDeviceName(uint16_t index, char name[webrtc::kAdmMaxDeviceNameSize], char guid[webrtc::kAdmMaxGuidSize]) 
{
    return -1;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::RecordingDeviceName(uint16_t index, char name[webrtc::kAdmMaxDeviceNameSize], char guid[webrtc::kAdmMaxGuidSize]) 
{
    return -1;
}

// Device selection
int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::SetPlayoutDevice(uint16_t index) 
{
    return 0;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::SetPlayoutDevice(WindowsDeviceType device) 
{
    return 0;
}

// Audio transport initialization
int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::PlayoutIsAvailable(bool* available) 
{
    LOG_MESSAGE("ADM was queried for PlayoutIsAvailable.");
    *available = false;
    return 0;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::InitPlayout() 
{
    LOG_ERROR("InitPlayout shouldn't have been called!");
    return -1;
}

bool FCustomAudioDeviceModule::PlayoutIsInitialized() const 
{
    return false;
}

// Audio transport control
int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::StartPlayout() 
{
    LOG_ERROR("StartPlayout shouldn't have been called!");
    return -1;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::StopPlayout() 
{
    LOG_ERROR("StopPlayout shouldn't have been called!");
    return -1;
}

bool FCustomAudioDeviceModule::Playing() const
{
    return false;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::SetRecordingDevice(uint16_t index)
{
    return 0;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::SetRecordingDevice(WindowsDeviceType device)
{
    return 0;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::RecordingIsAvailable(bool* available)
{
    LOG_MESSAGE("ADM was queried for RecordingIsAvailable.");
    *available = false;
    return 0;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::InitRecording()
{
    LOG_MESSAGE("ADM InitRecording");
    if (!AudioCapturer->IsInitialized())
    {
        AudioCapturer->Init();
    }

    return 0;
}

bool FCustomAudioDeviceModule::RecordingIsInitialized() const
{
    return AudioCapturer->IsInitialized();
}


int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::StartRecording() 
{
    LOG_MESSAGE("ADM StartRecording");
    AudioCapturer->StartCapturing();
    bIsRecording = true;
    return 0;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::StopRecording() 
{
    LOG_MESSAGE("ADM StopRecording");
    AudioCapturer->StopCapturing();
    bIsRecording = false;
    return 0;
}

bool FCustomAudioDeviceModule::Recording() const 
{
    return bIsRecording;
}

// Audio mixer initialization
int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::InitSpeaker() 
{
    return 0;
}

bool FCustomAudioDeviceModule::SpeakerIsInitialized() const 
{
    return false;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::InitMicrophone() 
{
    return 0;
}

bool FCustomAudioDeviceModule::MicrophoneIsInitialized() const 
{
    return true;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::SpeakerVolumeIsAvailable(bool* available) {
    *available = false;  // Indicate that volume control is not available
    return -1;  // Operation successful
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::SetSpeakerVolume(uint32_t volume) {
    return -1;  // Operation not supported
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::SpeakerVolume(uint32_t* volume) const {
    return -1;  // Operation successful
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::MaxSpeakerVolume(uint32_t* maxVolume) const {
    return -1;  // Operation successful
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::MinSpeakerVolume(uint32_t* minVolume) const {
    return -1;  // Operation successful
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::MicrophoneVolumeIsAvailable(bool* available) {
    return 0;  // Operation successful
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::SetMicrophoneVolume(uint32_t volume) {
    return 0;  // Operation not supported
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::MicrophoneVolume(uint32_t* volume) const {
    return 0;  // Operation successful
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::MaxMicrophoneVolume(uint32_t* maxVolume) const {
    *maxVolume = FWebRTCAudioCaptureComponent::MaxVolumeLevel;  // Arbitrary max volume
    return 0;  // Operation successful
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::MinMicrophoneVolume(uint32_t* minVolume) const {
    return 0;  // Operation successful
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::SpeakerMuteIsAvailable(bool* available) {
    *available = false;  // Indicate that mute control is not available
    return -1;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::SetSpeakerMute(bool enable) {
    return -1;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::SpeakerMute(bool* enabled) const {
    *enabled = false;  // Speaker is not muted
    return -1;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::MicrophoneMuteIsAvailable(bool* available) {
    *available = false;  // Indicate that mute control is not available
    return -1;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::SetMicrophoneMute(bool enable) {
    return -1;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::MicrophoneMute(bool* enabled) const {
    *enabled = false;  // Microphone is not muted
    return -1;  // Operation successful
}

// Stereo support
int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::StereoPlayoutIsAvailable(bool* available) const 
{
    *available = false;
    return 0;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::SetStereoPlayout(bool enable) 
{
    return 0;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::StereoPlayout(bool* enabled) const 
{
    *enabled = false;
    return 0;
}
int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::StereoRecordingIsAvailable(bool* available) const 
{
    *available = true;
    return 0;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::SetStereoRecording(bool enable) 
{
    return 0;
}

int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::StereoRecording(bool* enabled) const 
{
    *enabled = true;
    return 0;
}

// Playout delay
int32_t FCustomAudioDeviceModule::PlayoutDelay(uint16_t* delayMS) const 
{
    *delayMS = 0;
    return 0;
}

Here is the PeerConnection Creation logic:

void FWebRTCClient::CreatePeerConnection()
{
    if (!PeerConnectionFactory)
    {
        CreatePeerConnectionFactory();
    }

    std::vector<std::string> stunServers = {
        "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
        "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302",
        "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302",
        "stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302",
        "stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302"
    };

    webrtc::PeerConnectionInterface::RTCConfiguration Config;

    for (const auto& uri : stunServers) {
        webrtc::PeerConnectionInterface::IceServer StunServer;
        StunServer.uri = uri;
        Config.servers.push_back(StunServer);
    }
    
    webrtc::RTCErrorOr<rtc::scoped_refptr<TPeerConnection>> Result = PeerConnectionFactory->CreatePeerConnectionOrError(Config, webrtc::PeerConnectionDependencies(this));
    if (!Result.ok())
    {
        Delegate->OnWebRTCError(FString::Printf(TEXT("Failed to Create PeerConnectionObject: %s"), Result.error().message()));
        return;
    }

    // move object's ownership to the class.
    PeerConnection = Result.MoveValue();

    // Create an audio source. This might involve your custom audio capture logic.
    cricket::AudioOptions AudioOptions;

    rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::AudioSourceInterface> AudioSource = PeerConnectionFactory->CreateAudioSource(AudioOptions);
    rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::AudioTrackInterface> AudioTrack = PeerConnectionFactory->CreateAudioTrack("audioLabel", AudioSource);

    // Add the audio track to the peer connection
    auto AddTrackResult = PeerConnection->AddTrack(AudioTrack, { "streamId" }); // "streamId" is arbitrary and used to identify the stream
    if (!AddTrackResult.ok()) {
        // Handle the error
        Delegate->OnWebRTCError(FString::Printf(TEXT("Failed to add audio track: %s"), AddTrackResult.error().message()));
        return;
    }
}


void FWebRTCClient::CreatePeerConnectionFactory()
{
    NetworkThread = rtc::Thread::CreateWithSocketServer();
    NetworkThread->Start();

    WorkerThread = rtc::Thread::Create();
    WorkerThread->Start();

    SignallingThread = rtc::Thread::Create();
    SignallingThread->Start();

    rtc::scoped_refptr<FCustomAudioDeviceModule> AudioDeviceModule = new rtc::RefCountedObject<FCustomAudioDeviceModule>();
    rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::AudioProcessing> AudioProcessingModule = webrtc::AudioProcessingBuilder().Create();
    {
        webrtc::AudioProcessing::Config Config;
        // Enabled multi channel audio capture/render
        Config.pipeline.multi_channel_capture = true;
        Config.pipeline.multi_channel_render = true;
        Config.pipeline.maximum_internal_processing_rate = 48000;
        // Turn off all other audio processing effects in UE's WebRTC. We want to stream audio from UE as pure as possible.
        Config.pre_amplifier.enabled = false;
        Config.high_pass_filter.enabled = false;
        Config.echo_canceller.enabled = false;
        Config.noise_suppression.enabled = false;
        Config.transient_suppression.enabled = false;
        Config.gain_controller1.enabled = false;
        Config.gain_controller2.enabled = false;
#if !WEBRTC_5414
        Config.voice_detection.enabled = false;
        Config.residual_echo_detector.enabled = false;
        Config.level_estimation.enabled = false;
#endif

        // Apply the config.
        AudioProcessingModule->ApplyConfig(Config);
    }

    auto AudioEncoderFactory = webrtc::CreateAudioEncoderFactory<webrtc::AudioEncoderOpus>();
    auto AudioDecoderFactory = webrtc::CreateAudioDecoderFactory<webrtc::AudioDecoderOpus>();

    PeerConnectionFactory = webrtc::CreatePeerConnectionFactory(
                                    NetworkThread.get(),   // Network thread
                                    WorkerThread.get(),    // Worker thread
                                    SignallingThread.get(), // Signaling thread
                                    AudioDeviceModule,     // Audio device module
                                    AudioEncoderFactory,   // Audio Encoder Factory
                                    AudioDecoderFactory,   // Audio Decoder Factory
                                    nullptr,                
                                    nullptr,
                                    nullptr,
                                    AudioProcessingModule
                                );

    checkf(PeerConnectionFactory, TEXT("Failed to create peer connection factory!"));
}

I have been trying to understand what WebRTC does after I call the AudioTransport->RecordedDataIsAvailable() callback but I got lost in the codebase.
I feel like I am missing a very critical piece of information and would love any help I can get as I have been on this problem for couple of days.
Thanks,

Well, I solved it....
The code is perfectly fine, the issue was with the way I was calculating the 10ms frame lengths... I forgot to multiply the length with number of channels :D.
